# Timestamp in milliseconds doesn't gets converted to hours, minutes and seconds properly?

Tags: java, timestamp, milliseconds, nanotime

Below is my simple timer class which is working fine in simplest cases. I am using below timer class to measure how much time certain code takes in getting executed.

```
public static class StopTimer {

    public static StopTimer getInstance() {
        return new StopTimer();
    }

    private long m_end = -1;
    private long m_interval = -1;
    private final long m_start;

    private StopTimer() {
        m_start = m_interval = currentTime();
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        long result = 0;

        final long startTime = m_start;
        final long endTime = isTimerRunning() ? currentTime() : m_end;

        result = nanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);

        return result;
    }

    private long currentTime() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }

    private long nanoToMilliseconds(final long nanoseconds) {
        return nanoseconds / 1000000L;
    }
}
```

Below is how I am using the above timer class. I get the timestamp in milliseconds it takes to execute some piece of code and then convert that `timestamp` to`hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StopTimer timer = StopTimer.getInstance();

    some_code_which_I_am_measuring();

    long timeTaken = timer.getDuration();

    int seconds = (int) (timeTaken / 1000) % 60;
    int minutes = (int) ((timeTaken / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    int hours = (int) ((timeTaken / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);    

    System.out.println("Total Time Taken: " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");

}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

The problem I am facing is `timeTaken` timestamp doesn't gets converted to `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` properly. Meaning, if the code is running for total 2 minutes, then my `sys.out` shows correct result.

But suppose if this method `some_code_which_I_am_measuring` is running for two days, then my `sys.out` shows wrong result. As an example, I started my program on - `Fri 5/23/2014 9:40 PM` and it finished on `Sun 5/25/2014 9:38 PM` so my `sys.out` should tell me that it took `~48` hours something to execute the code. Right?

But in general it prints out -

`Total Time Taken: 23 hours 57 minutes 35 seconds`

which is wrong as you can see the date above it took 48 hours to complete the task.

Is there anything wrong in my above code?

**Update:-**

After adding days as well, overall timestamp should look like this?

```
int seconds = (int) (timeTaken / 1000) % 60;
int minutes = (int) ((timeTaken / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
int hours = (int) ((timeTaken / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
int days = (int) (timeTaken / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to take the number of hours and take the remainder when divided by `24`, unless you further plan to list the number of days it took also.

If hours is as far as you'll go with units, then take out the `% 24`:

```
int hours = (int) (timeTaken / (1000 * 60 * 60));
```

Then you'll see the correct output

```
Total Time Taken: 47 hours 57 minutes 35 seconds
```

Else, you may want to add a days calculation.

```
int days = ((timeTaken / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Then you can add that to the output, which would then show up as

```
Total Time Taken: 1 day 23 hours 57 minutes 35 seconds
```

Comment: aah silly mistake from me. If I need to go with days calculation, then what changes I am supposed to make?

Comment: You'll want to add another line, something like 'int days = ((timeTaken / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));`, and also print that value out.

Comment: I have updated the question with days as well. Can you see whether that's what you meant?

Comment: Can you check what I have updated, it is what you meant and my full timestamp logic will look like?